# Programatically added UIButton doesn't go away after switching scenes

Tags: swift, uibutton, skscene

I'm using a game app template in Swift 3 and when I transition from my 'start' screen to my 'Game' scene, the button from  the 'start' screen doesn't go away. **I read other people posts similar to this but nothing helped.** My button is a programatically added uibutton with a uibezierpath rounded rectangle behind the button to make it look nice. The problem is, it(the button, and the UIBezierpath) won't go away when I change scenes - it's in the exact same spot as the 'start' screen. 
My Button code with the UIBezierpath:

```
let playAgain = UIButton()
        playAgain.frame = CGRect(x: 225, y: 247, width: 115, height: 36)

        playAgain.backgroundColor = SKColor.lightGray
        playAgain.setTitle("Play", for: .normal)

    playAgain.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)

        self.view?.addSubview(playAgain)
        playAgain.addTarget(self, action: #selector(playAgainTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        //now for the bezierpath/ rounded rect
        //let doYourPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 100, height: 36))

        //this also works
        let roundRect = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 218, y: 240, width: 130, height: 50), cornerRadius: 18)
        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        layer.path = roundRect.cgPath
        layer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        layer.fillColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        self.view?.layer.addSublayer(layer)

func playAgainTapped(_ sender: Any?) -> Void {
        print("***********")

        backToGame()
    }
```

Switch scenes code:

```
func backToGame(){
        removeAllChildren()

        run(SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.wait(forDuration: 3.0),
            SKAction.run() {
                // 5
                let reveal = SKTransition.flipHorizontal(withDuration: 0.5)
                let scene = GameScene(size: self.size)
                self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition:reveal)
            }
            ]))
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What does `removeAllChildren` do?

Comment: @the4kman it removes the text from the button.

Answer (score 0):

You are presenting the scene on the same view as the button's superview.

Since the scene is independent from the views that are on the scene, your button will remain untouched, so you should explicitly remove the button if you want it to be removed.

Declare the button and the rounded rectangle **globally** and **remove them** from their superview/superlayer in `backToGame`.

```
let playAgain = UIButton()
let layer = CAShapeLayer()

func backToGame(){
    removeAllChildren()

    playAgain.removeFromSuperview()
    layer.removeFromSuperlayer()

    run(SKAction.sequence([
        SKAction.wait(forDuration: 3.0),
        SKAction.run() {
            // 5
            let reveal = SKTransition.flipHorizontal(withDuration: 0.5)
            let scene = GameScene(size: self.size)
            self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition:reveal)
        }
        ]))
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works!  Do you have a suggestion for a good article about views and this type of stuff?